# MultipartEntity: Content-Length for InputStream

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to send the data from an inputstream in a multipart/form-data, as a file-parameter using:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
            .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
            .addBinaryBody("file", inputStream)
            .build();
```

the problem is that the server seems to require a Content-Length header. I know the correct size of my inputStream - can I set it manually?

Comment: Can the `InputStream` fit in memory? Is that how you know its size?

Comment: No, the `InputStream` is an http-response which provides the content-length. But I want to "redirect" that (which already works but without providing the content-length).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the `addBinaryBody` method, you can create your own `FormBodyPart` with a `ContentBody`. The appropriate `ContentBody` is `InputStreamBody` but its `getContentLength` method returns `-1`.

I'd suggest you extend the class to provide a custom content length.

```
class KnownSizeInputStreamBody extends InputStreamBody {   
    private final long contentLength;

    public KnownSizeInputStreamBody(InputStream in, long contentLength, ContentType contentType) {
        super(in, contentType);
        this.contentLength = contentLength;
    }

    @Override
    public long getContentLength() {
        return contentLength;
    }
}
```

You can then create your multipart entity as

```
FormBodyPart bodyPart = FormBodyPartBuilder.create().setName("file")
        .setBody(new KnownSizeInputStreamBody(inputStream, contentLenth, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)).build();

HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart(bodyPart).build();
```

as appropriate (your own content type, content length, name, etc.).

In my case, the http client wrote the content-length for the entire multipart request body, not for each part.

Comment: That works great, thank you. For the filename-parameter I had to add `.setField("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"")` to the `FormBodyPartBuilder`.

Comment: @G.Rossi Ah no, don't do that. I think `InputStreamBody` has a constructor that accepts a filename. Use that one.

Comment: Oh I guess, I missed that one. But yes, you're right - that's better.

Comment: If you want to set a `Content-Length` header for a part, you can do `FormBodyPartBuilder.create().addField("Content-Length", "42")...`